# Finding Unique Values in 3 Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have 3 columns in excel. I want to find unique values in the columns A, B and C.

So:

1. by looking in column A, I want to find the unique values that are not in B or C.
2. by looking in column B, I want to find unique values that are not in column A or C.
3. by looking in Column C, I want to find unique values that are not in column A or B.

This is what I put in column A

```
=IF(OR(MATCH(A3,$B$3:$B$631,0),(MATCH(A3,$C$3:$C$408,0))),"Match",A3)
```

This is what I put in column B

```
=IF(OR(MATCH(B3,$A$3:$A$857,0),(MATCH(B3,$C$3:$C$408,0))),"Match",B3)
```

This is what I put in column C

```
=(IF(OR(MATCH(C3,$A$3:$A$857,0),(MATCH(C3,$B$3:$B$631,0))),"Match",C3)
```

This gives me duplicate values in the three columns I need them to be unique. Maybe I'm just making this very complicated. Any idea on how to do this?

The table example:

```
A   B   C
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   7   7
4   8   11
5   9   12
6   10  13
```

In this instance, for I want the unique # in each column. So, for column A the unique values that are not in columns B or C are = to 1,4,5,6. In column B the unique values, that are not in A or C, are =8,9, 10. In column C the unique values, that are not in B or C are = 11, 12, 13. I want to make a formula in columns D, E, F for these three formulas.

---

A   B   C
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   7   7
4   8   11
5   9   12
6   10  13

In this instance, for I want the unique # in each column. So, for column A the unquie values that are not in columns B or C are = to 1,4,5,6. In column B the unique values, that are not in A or C, are =8,9, 10. In column C the unique values, that are not in B or C are = 11, 12, 13. I want to make a formula in columnc D, E, F for these three formulas.

Comment: Put them all into one column (you can give each a second column if you need to know which column they origintated from), sort,  then do a test to see if a cell is different to its neighbours.  If so, it is unique.

Comment: @user339937: A picture is worth several hundred words. Can you post some sort of representation (i.e., example) of what your data look like and what you want Excel to do for you? And: you say, “… looking in column A, I want to find the unique values that are not in B or C.” So if `A17` is “orange” and `A42` is also “orange”, but “orange” does not appear in columns B and C, does that count as a unique value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formula<sup>†</sup> like the following in D1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A$1:$A$6,$B$1:$B$6,0))*ISERROR(MATCH($A$1:$A$6,$C$1:$C$6,0)),ROW($A$1:$A$6)),ROW())),"")
```

The formulae in the other columns are similar:

E1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$6,SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B$1:$B$6,$A$1:$A$6,0))*ISERROR(MATCH($B$1:$B$6,$C$1:$C$6,0)),ROW($B$1:$B$6)),ROW())),"")
```

F1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$6,SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH($C$1:$C$6,$A$1:$A$6,0))*ISERROR(MATCH($C$1:$C$6,$B$1:$B$6,0)),ROW($C$1:$C$6)),ROW())),"")
```

And from your example table, I get these:

[image]

If your formula starts on a different row than the first, the formula will need to be changed a bit because it uses `ROW()` which is dependent on the row the formula is placed in.

<sup>†</sup> Note: To use the formula, you have to press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after inserting it.

Comment: What does the SMALL stand for? My actual data has a alphanum combination. This will not affect it will it?I tried the formula and its giving me values that are in other columns, not unique values.

Comment: @user339937 `SMALL` will return the `n`th smallest value from a set of values. It is being applies on row number, not on the actual data. And for the other part, make sure that the ranges are correctly changed. E.g. $C$1:$C$6 might become $C$1:$C$500 and you will need to change this everywhere in the formula.